# Asymptotic solution to $\cot(x)=\lambda x$

Tags: trigonometry, asymptotics, roots

I need to solve $\cot(x)=\lambda x$ in the interval $(0,\pi)$ and where $\lambda\gg1$. I know that my solution is very close to zero, I've tried with the assumption $x\sim\lambda^{-1}$, but I haven't been able to find an analytical approximation for $x$.. any hints or ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing, as Paul Enta did, $$\lambda^{-1}=x\tan x$$ you can have extremely good approximations using Padé approximants.

The simplest would let you with
$$\lambda^{-1}=\frac{x^2}{1-\frac{1}{3}x^2}\implies x^2=\frac{3}{3 \lambda +1}$$ the next would let you with
$$\lambda^{-1}=\frac{x^2-\frac{2 }{21}x^4}{1-\frac{3} {7}x^2+\frac{1}{105}x^4}$$ which is just a quadratic equation in $x^2$.

For example, using $\lambda=10$, the first one will give
$$x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{3}{31}}\approx \pm 0.31108551$$
the second one
$$x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{202} \left(1095-\sqrt{1156605}\right)}\approx \pm 0.31105285$$ while the "exact" solution would be $x \approx \pm 0.31105285$.

**Edit**

We could even do simpler focusing on $[2,2n]$ Padé approximants and just set to $0$ the numerator. This would give
$$x^2_{(1)}=\frac{3}{3 \lambda +1}$$
$$x^2_{(2)}=\frac{5 (3 \lambda +1)}{15 \lambda ^2+10 \lambda +2}$$
$$x^2_{(3)}=\frac{21 \left(15 \lambda ^2+10 \lambda +2\right)}{315 \lambda ^3+315 \lambda
   ^2+119 \lambda +17}$$
$$x^2_{(4)}=\frac{9 \left(315 \lambda ^3+315 \lambda ^2+119 \lambda +17\right)}{2835 \lambda
   ^4+3780 \lambda ^3+2079 \lambda ^2+558 \lambda +62}$$
$$x^2_{(5)}=\frac{55 \left(2835 \lambda ^4+3780 \lambda ^3+2079 \lambda ^2+558 \lambda
   +62\right)}{155925 \lambda ^5+259875 \lambda ^4+187110 \lambda ^3+72600 \lambda
   ^2+15202 \lambda +1382}$$

**Edit**

Based on the above results, let us write $$x=\pm\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {a_i}{\lambda^i}}$$ and expand. The resulting coefficients are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
i & a_i \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & -\frac{1}{3} \\
 3 & \frac{4}{45} \\
 4 & -\frac{16}{945} \\
 5 & \frac{16}{14175} \\
 6 & \frac{64}{93555} \\
 7 & -\frac{69248}{212837625} \\
 8 & \frac{512}{8292375} \\
 9 & \frac{211712}{32564156625} \\
 10 & -\frac{336729088}{38979295480125}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Below are given some results for even small values of $\lambda$.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \lambda & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 0.860332160371796 &  0.860333589019380 \\
 2 & 0.653271186102058 &  0.653271187094403 \\
 3 & 0.547160757246327 &  0.547160757260330 \\
 4 & 0.480094436956711 &  0.480094436957391 \\
 5 & 0.432840719904754 &  0.432840719904819 \\
 6 & 0.397248064219170 &  0.397248064219170 \\
 7 & 0.369197229001779 &  0.369197229001779 \\
 8 & 0.346354126703749 &  0.346354126703749 \\
 9 & 0.327284672964038 &  0.327284672964038 \\
 10 & 0.311052848200298 & 0.311052848200298
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 7):

A simple answer is obtained by remarking that
$$ \lambda^{-1}=x\tan x$$ has a solution near $x=0$ when $\lambda\gg1$. In this region, $\tan x\sim x$. Thus $x\sim\pm\lambda^{-\tfrac{1}{2}}$.

A series expansion in $\lambda^{-1/2}$can be obtained using the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem):
$$x\sim \pm \lambda^{-\tfrac{1}{2}}\mp \frac{1}{6}\lambda^{-\tfrac{3}{2}}...$$

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to the excellent answers already given, I would point out that for $\lambda\gg 1$, by [the Shafer-Fink inequality](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0753) a decent approximation of the solution is given by 
$$ x\approx \arctan\,\left(\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\lambda^2}+\frac{3}{\lambda}+\frac{2 \sqrt{1+3 \lambda+9 \lambda^2}}{\lambda^2}}\right)$$
and the fact that $x=\Theta(\lambda^{-1/2})$ is pretty clear from the fact that $x\cot x=1-\frac{x^2}{3}-O(x^4)$ in a right neighbourhood of the origin.

Comment: First of all, all my congratulations for your election as moderator. Second, you paper is very interesting.

Comment: If no typo, using the approximation you give, we should get $x^2=\frac 1 \lambda+\frac 1 {\lambda^2}+O(\frac 1 {\lambda^3})$. Tha $+$ is strange to me. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: of course you are right, sir. I performed the wrong substitution before, now fixed. My approximation has the following asymptotic behaviour as $\lambda\to +\infty$: $$x^2 = \frac{1}{\lambda}-\frac{1}{3\lambda^2}+\frac{17}{180\lambda^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{\lambda^4}\right).$$

Comment: Good to know ! Did you notice your $17/180$ compared to the $4/45=16/180$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: yes, it is a pretty accurate pseudo-algebraic approximation, and it can be made even more accurate by exploiting the generalized version of the SF inequality. In such a case, however, the argument of $\arctan\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{\cdot}$ becomes way messier.